# Java, escape character confusion

Tags: java, escaping, string-formatting

I have a simple question:
This code works and connects to Pro2_PGM006 access point.
If I have string variable , how I must modify string "\"Pro2_PGM006\"" ???

Thank you in advance,

```
            config.SSID = "\"Pro2_PGM006\"";    
            config.preSharedKey = "\"*********\"";
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);}
            wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.startScan();
            //delay(1000);
            int newId = -1;
            int tries = 0;
            while (newId == -1 && tries <=10) {
                newId = getExistingNetworkId("\"Pro2_PGM006\"");
                tries++;
            }
            if (tries >= 10) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Cannot find WIFI", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(0xFFFF0000));
            }

                wifiManager.enableNetwork(newId, true);
```

Comment: How are you trying to modify the string? If you want to take away the `\ "`'s, just remove it from your string. Are you asking how to do so programmatically?

Comment: I have -String AP_name = "Pro2_PGM006"; How can I add the escape characters?? Like "\ + AP_name + \"" which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh. Just use double backslashes, like `\\\`. That way it knows to escape the next character, which is a backslash as well.

Comment: Just as you did in your code: a double quote is escaped by a backslash. So you use `"\"" + AP_name + "\""`.

Comment: Dear JB Nizet, It worked. Thank you. How can I mark your answer as correct? I think that you must "answer" my question first!